# Copy/Paste from Firefox to Terminal (Urxvt)

Tags: firefox, clipboard

I'm having a curious issue copying text from web pages to my terminal (to copy and paste a command for instance). Ctrl-c/Ctrl-v have never worked with the terminal since there are the two separate buffers. However, when I highlighted text, it was automatically added to some buffer from which I can paste onto the terminal (with middle-click or shift+insert).

This doesn't work anymore.

Interestingly, however, it DOES work from the Firefox addressbar. So I can ctrl-c text from a webpage, paste it using ctrl-v onto my address bar, and from there the highlight/ctrl-insert works again.

**Edit:**

Ah I've found the issue.

Firefox Clipboard.autocopy setting was off. I believe I turned it off some days/weeks ago in order to prevent the issue where Firefox seems to go back when you middle-click. That is controlled by Middlemouse.contentLoadURL but I think I turned off both.

Comment: Interesting.  I assume you had to goto about:config to edit this setting?  You might post your edit as an answer, and then click the tic-mark on the answer to indicate that it is accepted.

Answer (score 7):

To paste in the terminal, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> as a key based shortcut, or right click in the terminal and choose paste - This works for me for pasting text from a webpage on firefox into the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay.

Firefox Clipboard.autocopy setting was off. I believe I turned it off some days/weeks ago in order to prevent the issue where Firefox seems to go back when you middle-click. That is controlled by Middlemouse.contentLoadURL but I think I turned off both.